# Will my files also be deleted from local UbuntuOne folders?

Tags: ubuntu-one

UbuntuOne is shutting down, and today we all received an email informing us of the following:

> While the service will stop as of 1 June, you will have an additional
>   two months (until 31 July 2014) to collect all of your content. After
>   that date, all remaining content will be deleted.

From *where* will the content be deleted? Only from their servers? Or do I need to fear that I will also lose local data?

Answer (score 1):

After June 1, the local client won't be able to connect to the server. So, on July 31, the data can only be deleted from the server, because the client won't be connected, and thus won't be able to synchronize any deletion that happens.